# Custom file name extension for Apache webserver

Tags: web-hosting, lamp

I pay for a very common LAMP webhost. I was wondering if I could have  custom extensions for my files. Let' say I have this url, for instance:

```
http://www.mysite/custom.php

how do I change that to something like:

http://www.mysite/custom.name
```

just to give an example.

Notice I'm not mentioning changing the index.php. I have a XAMPP server setup here in my PC, and it works just fine, with out altering anything. Can that be accomplished on an LAMP webhost?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is YES.

You'll have to make a few configuration adjustments of course.

But why would you want to do that?  It makes things messy, hard to maintain, and may cause some application incompatibilities if you are not careful.

Comment: ok, do you know what those are?

Comment: i mean the changes i have to make? thank you.

Comment: If I were to do something like this I'd be looking at http://httpd.apache.org specifically with the directives concerning the mod_rewrite and the mod_mime modules that are standard and applying them accordingly.